# unable to send large data via email using php

Tags: php

I have a php file 'report.php' which basically prints out in html format rows and rows of tabular data fetched from mysql.

I'm fetching this file (as shown in the code below) and feeding into dashboard.php for viewing it on-screen and it works perfectly. The report shows every line.

```
 ob_start();
 ob_implicit_flush(true);
 ob_end_flush();
 include('report.php');
 $output = ob_get_contents();
```

However, the problem is when i try to email this report to a user, the report won't get sent out due to the large number of records. I tested this by reducing the count of data and the report gets emailed immediately.

This is my code to fetch report.php and send via email

```
<?php    
ob_start();
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_clean();
include('report.php');
$output = ob_get_contents();    
$to = 'me@email.com';    
$subject = 'Weekly Report';    
$headers = "From: " . "noreply@website.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";        
mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers); 
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

How can i solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps zipping it or breaking it into parts?

Comment: My next attempt is to check the counter size and break it up if everything else fails.

Comment: Or save as local file and email link to the file once it is complete

Comment: You mean convert to pdf?

Comment: Just something local either html or pdf and then the email just contains a link to load that directly from the server so that the size of the email would be small